# Separate data from text file and plot the graph using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have the data in the following format

```
+CMT: "+944434556","","17/06/20,13:51:21+22" Level 255mm
```

And I want to plot a graphic between time on x axis and 255 on y axis. Can you please let me know the code for the above?

Comment: To help me understand better, can you show more lines of your data file ? What part of the time do you want to display in the x-axis (hours, date, +944434556,...)?

Comment: from this +CMT: "+944434556","","17/06/20,13:51:21+22" Level 255mm,  i want 13:51:21 on x axis and 255 on y axis.

Comment: I am getting data in this format +CMT: "+944434556","","17/06/20,13:51:21+22" Level 255mm coninuously from sim cards. Now i have to plot a graph between time 13:51:21 on x axis and 255 on y axis

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think you want :

```
plot "<awk -F'[, +m\"]' '{print $5, $16, $12}' datafile.dat" u 1:2:xtic(3) notitle
```

where `datafile.dat` contains your data.

In order to find the location on the x-axis, I assumed that `944434556` also represent the time. So the point is in reality set at `(944434556,255)` but the plot displays `13:51:21`. Of course, you could also do :

```
plot "<awk -F'[, +m\"]' '{print $16, $12}' datafile.dat" u 1:xtic(2) notitle
```

Comment: when i am trying to run the above code i am getting an error   cannot create pipe for data

Comment: does `awk -F'[, +m\"]' '{print $5, $16, $12}' datafile.dat` work for you ? (simply run this in a terminal where `datafile.dat` is located)

Comment: No its not working. It is throwing an error undefined variable: awk